# The ending of Fire and Hemlock

Tags: diana-wynne-jones, fire-and-hemlock

If there is anyone out there that understands the ending of *Fire and Hemlock*, I'd be very grateful for a detailed explanation. The ending corresponds approximately to Part 4 (Nowhere), Section 6, where

> Polly comes to save Tom. Specifically, the part set in the magical swimming pool.

I think I first read that section 20 years ago, but I still don't really know what happens here.

The relevant section starts around the words:

> At first sight it seemed to be autumn in the garden.

*Fire and Hemlock* was, of course, written by the late great Diana Wynne Jones. She is unaccountably missing from this site, so I'm happy to remedy this omission.

Comment: What is confusing about this ending?

Comment: Hi Hamlet. Well, I don't understand what happened. Judging from what I've read over the years, I'm far from alone. And I've never heard of a clear detailed explanation of it either. Possibly everyone is afraid of spoiling the book.

Comment: If it's not clear what I mean by "the ending" I could elaborate.

Comment: 'At first sight it seemed to be autumn in the garden' is a great opening line. I haven't read the book so I can't comment.

Comment: I edited out some of the inessential spoilertagging. In general you should try to hide as little as possible of your question, so that it makes as much sense as possible even without the hidden bits. (I wasn't sure about "*At first sight it seemed to be autumn in the garden.*" - it doesn't **seem** spoilery, but then again I haven't read the book - so I left that line hidden.)

Comment: There are two blog posts that give an explanation of the ending. [Here](http://rushthatspeaks.livejournal.com/254549.html) and [here](http://rushthatspeaks.dreamwidth.org/401546.html). I'm not sure that's the only interpretation, but the  blogger has certainly noticed some very relevant things.

Comment: Hi @PeterShor: I looked at the two blog posts. I don't think the  2007
Rush-That-Speaks entry was trying to explain the ending - those mostly look like Eliot comparisons. OTOH, he or she is clearly trying to explain it in the 2011 entry, which seems to be at least partly an eulogy for DWJ, who had just died. It was a shock for all of us. However, I don't understand the explanation. It reads like a cross between some very obscure literary criticism and a math proof. If you understand it, please do elaborate.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Technically "At first sight it seemed to be autumn in the garden." isn't an opening line. It occurs well into a section (or chapter). But it feels like a reasonable place to mark the scene I have in mind.

Comment: @Faheem: The 2007 post was intended as the first in a series of two posts that together explained the end. And as I said, I'm not sure that I agree with everything in the blog posts, but it's clear that they have noticed some details that are very relevant to figuring out the ending.

Comment: (SPOILERS!) Having reread the book now, I think the explanation in the blog posts is very good. Laurel is going to sacrifice Tom so as to extend her and Morton Leroy's lives. Polly objects that Morton Leroy broke the rules by seriously injuring Tom in the Castle of Horrors. Laurel agrees, and in compensation sets up a contest between Morton and Tom: whoever loses the contest ends up as the sacrifice. But she sets the rules of the contest to favor Morton. The perverse rules of the contest, and how Polly arranges it so Tom wins, are spelled out quite well in the second of the two blog posts.

Comment: (MORE SPOILERS!) Maybe you were confused by all the references to T.S. Eliot's *Four Quartets* in the blog posts. In her essay *The Heroic Ideal: A Personal Odyssey,* Diana Wynne Jones discusses how she wrote *Fire and Hemlock* and how she used *Four Quartets* for inspiration and structure. But the ending should be perfectly comprehensible without having read or understood *Four Quartets.*

Comment: @PeterShor Sounds like you should write an answer, provided you can make sense of the horse.

Comment: This article has a very good interpretation
https://hashtagsarahwrites.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/solving-fire-and-hemlock-massive-spoilers/comment-page-1/